# C# how to assign a type to a generic type in AddScoped using interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, inversion-of-control

I'm wanting to do a generic scoped.
I have a class where it needs to receive a "T" type to instantiate it. My problem is receiving this type "T" otherwise without being explicit.

example:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IMyInterface<T> where T : class {}

public interface IMyInterface<T> where T : class {}

public void test()
{
   Type xx = new someClass1().GetType();
   Type tt = new someClass2().GetType();
   Type yy = new someClass3().GetType();

   services.AddScoped<IMyInterface<xx>, MyClass<xx>>();
   services.AddScoped<IMyInterface<tt>, MyClass<tt>>();
   services.AddScoped<IMyInterface<yy>, MyClass<yy>>();
}
```

Another example

```
public void test()
{
   foreach (Type item in someClass.ToList())
   {
      services.AddScoped<IMyInterface<item>, MyClass<item>>();
   }
}
```

Comment: With adittional information: there is overloaded `ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped` which is not generic and take some interesting for you parameters...

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with the following code:
`var constructed1 = typeof(IMyInterface<>).MakeGenericType(item);
var constructed2 = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(item);
services.AddScoped(constructed1 , constructed2 );`

Answer (score -1):

This allows the MyMethod method to create an instance of T using the new operator. Note that this approach requires that the type parameter T be constrained in some way in order to be used without being explicitly specified.

```
public void MyMethod<T>() where T : new()
{
    T instance = new T();
    // code
}
```

Comment: This kind of approach is not what I'm looking for, I need to generate a type at compile time and pass that type dynamically into the <T> in MyClass.